# stuck with multi UIViewController modal

Tags: iphone, ios5, xcode4.3

I have lot of `UIViewController. Example

**UIViewController 0 - FirstView**

i add #import "MainMenuViewController.h" both in .h file and .m file.
a button inside my XIB with code:

```
- (IBAction)nextBtn:(id)sender
{
    MainMenuViewController *mainmenuData = [[MainMenuViewController alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];        
    self.mainmenuView = mainmenuData;
    mainmenuView.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    [self presentModalViewController:mainmenuView animated:YES];
}
```

**UIViewController 1 - MainMenu**

i add #import "Process1ViewController.h" both in .h file and .m file.
a button inside my XIB with code:

```
- (IBAction)nextBtn:(id)sender
{
    Process1ViewController *process1Data = [[Process1ViewController alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];        
    self.process1View = process1Data;
    process1View.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    [self presentModalViewController:process1View animated:YES];
}
```

**UIViewController 2 - Process1**

i add #import "Process2ViewController.h" both in .h file and .m file.
a button inside my XIB with code:

```
- (IBAction)nextBtn:(id)sender
{
    Process2ViewController *process2Data = [[Process2ViewController alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];        
    self.process2View = process2Data;
    process2View.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    [self presentModalViewController:process2View animated:YES];
}
```

**UIViewController 3 - Process2**

i add #import "ResultViewController.h" both in .h file and .m file.
a button inside my XIB with code:

```
- (IBAction)nextBtn:(id)sender
{
    ResultViewController *resultData = [[ResultViewController alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];        
    self.resultView = resultData;
    resultView.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    [self presentModalViewController:resultView animated:YES];
}
```

**UIViewController 4 - Result**

i add #import "MainMenuViewController.h" both in .h file and .m file.
a button inside my XIB with code:

```
- (IBAction)nextBtn:(id)sender
{
    MainMenuViewController *mainmenuData = [[MainMenuViewController alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];        
    self.mainmenuView = mainmenuData;
    mainmenuView.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    [self presentModalViewController:mainmenuView animated:YES];
}
```

here, i get this error point to my ResultViewController.h :

```
Unknown type name 'MainMenuViewController'; did you mean 'UIPageViewController'?

 - In file included from
   /Users/Whatever/Desktop/Project1/Project1/FirstViewController.m:9:
 - In file included from
   /Users/Whatever/Desktop/Project1/Project1/FirstViewController.h:10:
 - In file included from
   /Users/Whatever/Desktop/Project1/Project1/../MainMenuViewController.h:10:
 - In file included from
   /Users/Whatever/Desktop/Project1/Project1/../Process1.h:10:
 - In file included from
   /Users/Whatever/Desktop/Project1/Project1/../Process1.h:10:
 - 'UIPageViewController' declared here
```

Others error:

```
Unknown type name 'MainMenuViewController'; did you mean 'FirstViewController'?

 - In file included from
   /Users/Whatever/Desktop/Project1/Project1/FirstAppDelegate.m:11:
 - In file included from
   /Users/Whatever/Desktop/Project1/Project1/FirstViewController.h:10:
 - In file included from
   /Users/Whatever/Desktop/Project1/Project1/../MainMenuViewController.h:10:
 - In file included from
   /Users/Whatever/Desktop/Project1/Project1/../Process1ViewController.h:10:
 - In file included from
   /Users/Whatever/Desktop/Project1/Project1/../Process2ViewController.h:10:
 - 'FirstViewController' declared here
```

it seems i am using more than one modal for one ViewController (MainMenuViewController), right? how do i fix it. Please help me solve my problem.

Comment: why not use UINavigationController?

Comment: I don't understand your question very well, if you can explain what the app's trying to do could be better. Do you have your main menu in a modal view or it is in your main view?

Comment: @SyntaxError check out storyboards, they can really help with this situation.

Comment: With story board you can go to any controller in hierarchy

Comment: you can achieve the required navigation using the navigationcontroller in storybord

Comment: hey, i figure out! just like both of you said, using storyboard and navigation controller! thank you for help